# Loading data to Dhtmlx scheduler from database using java

Tags: java, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am completely new to the Dhtmlx Scheduler.I need to load data from the database to the scheduler.Now i am loading data to the scheduler by using the code

```
     scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2013,3,24),"day");
     scheduler.load("./data/events.xml");
```

But by using this code i can only load data from an xml file.I need to use javacode for loading the content.Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should definately use dhtmlxConnector for Java:
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxConnector/index.shtml

Here is a direct link to download it. It includes all related samples.
http://www.dhtmlx.com/x/download/regular/dhtmlxConnector_java.zip